# Custom non-username/password based login with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication

The jist of this question is about how to override CakePHP's auth component login function to log a user in based on something other than the default username and password.

So, we're developing a custom login function for one of our partners. Basically, the solution provides online courses to a number of companies who want to provide their clients and/or employees with in house training material.

This particular solution takes a home loan account number and personal identification number and does some algorithm validation and logs the user in. Or at least - that's what it should do.

Currently, the auth component tries to user a particular model to compare username and hashed password. Is there anyway to override this particular behaviour and get the Authcomponent to log the user in using the algorithm (glorified regex check) in a custom function? It should completely ignore the need for a username and password. In addition we won't actually have these account numbers and ID numbers stored anywhere. They will each be checked for certain related patterns.

Cheers

Comment: Just use your own custom Auth adapter then. It can be anything and will be able to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Hey Mark. Thanks. While my exposure to general Cake has left me with a lot of knowledge I'm afraid that my exposure to the auth component and speak of adapaters has me confused :D. Any chance you could put it in a mini rough sketch on where to start or where to look to read up on this. That would be great.

Comment: [here's a mini rough sketch](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom your login with authenticate property :

In your appController

```
  public $components = array(
            'Session',
            'Auth' => array(

                'authError' => "You don't have accès",
                'authorize' => array('Controller'),
                authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array('userModel' => 'MyUserModel', 
                        'fields'       => array('username' => 'numberuser','password' => 'personnalId'),
                        )
            )
        );
```